# Export Viewarray object textView text

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdata

I'm developing an app to create as many notes as you want, something like post-it's. I'm adding views and putting the into a viewArray

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
NoteViewController *noteController = [[NoteViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NoteViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:noteController.view];
UIView *myAddedView = (UIView *)[noteController view];

[viewArray insertObject:myAddedView atIndex:0];
noteController.myTextView.tag = viewArray.count;}
```

As you can see, I'm adding tags to textviews in the noteController even after the cast to addviews so I can get the textview text by the time I want to export the content from all textviews created.

```
- (IBAction)export:(id)sender{
NSData *myData;
NSInteger *cont = (NSInteger *)viewArray.count;
for (UIView *subviewa in [self.view subviews])
{
    if(cont>0)
        if (subviewa.tag == 0)
        myData = (NSData *)[subviewa viewWithTag:1];

        NSLog(@"%@", myData);
    }
    cont--;
 }
```

When I clic Export I get

```
<UITextView: 0x684a130; frame = (6 0; 84 92); text = 'my text'; clipsToBounds = YES;
 autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x684a310>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

As far as I know, this is a nsdata. I've tried JSON, casting... and when I try to access text property the app crashes. I need help to access textviews texts from all objects in viewarray. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any view has it's subviews array. So when you add textview to view, and there is no other objects in this view, you car refer to textview like this:

```
[subviewa.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

And get text property like this:

```
[(UITextView *)[subviewa.subviews objectAtIndex:0] text];
```

Code of `export:` method to return all views from array and display their textviews text:

```
- (IBAction)export:(id)sender{
    for (UIView *subviewa in [self.view subviews])
    {
        NSLog(@"SUBVIEW %@", (NSData *)subviewa);
        NSLog(@"TEXTVIEW TEXT IN SUBVIEW %@", [(UITextView *)[subviewa.subviews objectAtIndex:0] text]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rafael, I realized that the object I needed has the same position in the array regardless the subviews:         for (UIView *subviewa in [self.view subviews])
    {
        
        NSLog(@"SUBVIEW %@", (NSData *)subviewa);
        if ([subviewa.subviews count] == 2)
            
        
        NSLog(@"TEXTVIEW TEXT IN SUBVIEW %@", [(UITextView *)[subviewa.subviews objectAtIndex:1] text]);
        //NSLog(@"TEXTVIEW TEXT IN SUBVIEW %d", [subviewa.subviews count] );
    }